# Accesing data inside NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, parsing, nsdictionary

I know many have asked the same question, but their answers aren't working for me.

My question is,

> How can I access the **"value"** inside the trailer NSDictionary?

[image: trailer NSDictionary]

Comment: What is the "trailer NSDictionary"?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez i tried that but it says "Type NSData has no subscript members"

Comment: Are you trying to read a plist file?

Comment: I hadn't seen your image, but it seems like the value you want is inside a dictionary that's inside a dictionary, you can do `trailer["otherDictionary"]["key"]`. Your image doesn't show what's the key to the other dictionary, but it shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Comment: @CodeDifferent No,  I'm reading JSON from a data server

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yeah, thats what I thought, but like you say, it doesn't show the key for that dictionary, so I don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look carefully at your log's picture: it's `[NSDictionary]`, not `NSDictionary`. :)

Your princess is in another castle! I mean, `trailer` is not a dictionary, it's an *array* containing a dictionary.

Like:

```
trailer[0]["key"]
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tried this before, but with ["0"] instead of [0]. Thanks again

Comment: How can you spot the few light-grey pixels forming those brackets??

Comment: @CouchDeveloper It happened the other way: I had a hunch for the answer, then a close look at the picture confirmed it. :)